# Assigning variables to a C++ object

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm new to C++ and am coming out with the following error when assigning values to an object:

`JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: non-zero capacity for nullptr pointer: 8968320`

This is the class which I am trying to assign a value to:

```
class DirtyRegion
{
 public:
    DirtyRegion():dirtyRects(0), numRects(0), maxRects(0) {}
    ~DirtyRegion() {}

 public:

    ARect *dirtyRects; // Array of Rects

    int    numRects; // Number of Dirty Rects in the Array

    int    maxRects; // Size of Array
};
```

I think the top line in the constructor is initialising the object, but I'm not totally sure. As you can see this has a variable of type "ARect", which is the NDK equivalent of the android.graphics.Rect:

```
typedef struct ARect {
#ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef int32_t value_type;
#endif
    /// Minimum X coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t left;
    /// Minimum Y coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t top;
    /// Maximum X coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t right;
    /// Maximum Y coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t bottom;
} ARect;
```

In the main method I am creating an instance using this line:

```
android::DirtyRegion dirtyRegion;
```

This works fine, however, if I assign values to the objects variables I get errors. e.g:

```
dirtyRegion.maxRects = 0;
```

Am I missing something basic here?

Thanks!

Comment: That's obviously a JNI error, not a c++ error.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the error occurs at `dirtyRegion.maxRects = 0;`. So where exactly _does_ it occur?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - So when running this code I do get a JNI error, but this may be due to an exception getting thrown on the Android side of the code, rather than on the C++ (hope that's clear). All I can see is that when a value is assigned to the object then a JNI error occurs, but the C++ error is somthing I cannot see.

Answer (score 1):

dirtyRects is created as a null pointer, so you would need to allocate memory before accessing the elements. Instead, consider using a std::vector.

```
#include <vector>

struct ARect {
#ifdef __cplusplus
    typedef int32_t value_type;
#endif
    ARect(int _l=0, int _t=0, int _r=0, int _b=0):
        left(_l), top(_t), right(_r), bottom(_b) {}
    /// Minimum X coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t left;
    /// Minimum Y coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t top;
    /// Maximum X coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t right;
    /// Maximum Y coordinate of the rectangle.
    int32_t bottom;
};

class DirtyRegion
{
 public:
    DirtyRegion():dirtyRects(0), numRects(0), maxRects(0) {}
    ~DirtyRegion() {}

 public:

    std::vector<ARect> dirtyRects; // Array of Rects
    int    numRects; // Number of Dirty Rects in the Array
    int    maxRects; // Size of Array
};

int main()
{
    DirtyRegion dirtyRegion;
    dirtyRegion.dirtyRects.push_back(ARect(0,0,0,0));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Would have never thought to do something like that.